# Host name not working on IIS 8.5 when configuration are the same

Tags: iis-8, self-hosting, domain-name, fqdn

Sorry in advance, this is my first post and I'm a novice with web hosting.

I have 2 websites hosted on the same IIS version 8.5 using a different application pool.

The problem is that I can't get Website A to connect outside the network whereas website B can connect just fine.

They have the same configuration except for the bindings.

I tried switching the port in the bindings from A to B and the problem still arises.

Example: https All Unassigned 25777 analytics.com (A) https all unassigned 25779 portal.com (B)

Since I was able to switch the port and portal still works, I'm assuming that the site configuration is fine and the port is fine.

I think the host name's problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run a report and see if obvious issues can be identified.

Comment: I'm working on Window, IIS 8.5. There's no troubleshoot menu on the bottom right pan. Thanks

Comment: Maximize the window and you might see it. There are some WinForms layout issues.

Comment: I maximized the window. On the right hand pan, the words in special characters are 'Actions', 'Edit Site', 'Manage Website', 'Browse Website' and 'Configure'. Troubleshoot is not there. You thin it's located somewhere else on the Window IIS manager?

Comment: "Windows IIS Manager"? Clearly I didn't ask you to use that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're asking me to download your program instead of using the window's one right?

Comment: Yes. If Microsoft implements such a feature, we don't need any separate tools.

Answer (score 1):

The public IP was an issue. 
The public IP provided by our ISP wasn't properly configured. Changing to a new one provided it by them allowed us to access the website from outside the network.